# Hills closest to East Anglia

Tags: walking, uk

I live in [Felixstowe](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Felixstowe,+Suffolk/@51.9265855,1.705288,8z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x47d97635581d89a3:0x821bdd4b6b3e6df0) in East Anglia.  It's rather flat around here - and we enjoy hill walking.  We've not been for a good walking holiday for some time, mainly due to having children.

Whilst we can get to the likes of the Peak District in around 4 hours for a holiday, I'd like to know if there are any localised hills that may not be well known outside of their particular area that are closer by to us that would potentially be a day trip away to introduce the kids to the type of walking we like, and see how they get on.  Ideally they'd be fairly rural, with some worthwhile views at the top.

Comment: Oh, that's a tough one. Pretty much flat for about 200 miles of there...

Comment: Is it the altitude, the lack of level ground or the wildness that is of importance to you? I mean would something wild and flat be OK?

Comment: It's more for the experience of (fairly) continuous elevation/altitude changes - we have some wonderful places for walking locally, but that's a very different experience to hills.  The "worthwhile views" could be exchanged equally with something else that may provide a sense of achievement to the kids

Comment: Further away than the Chilterns Liam suggested but a lovely place for a holiday is the [Cotswolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotswolds) but not so good for a day drive...

Comment: @JamesThorpe, can you now accept one of the answers? It is the way the site is supposed to work.

Answer (score 5):

What about the Chilterns (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiltern_Hills)

[Relatively near](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Chilterns+Area+of+Outstanding+Natural+Beauty/@51.681974,-0.769593,8z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xdea1d4697751d669), though not very high

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the Chilterns are certainly one option - though it does mean a trip on the M25 :)  I was hoping there might be one or two hills that may be closer, though with the geology of the area, it's pretty unlikely!

Comment: @JamesThorpe I live in the Chilterns and there really is plenty to do (shame you'd have to venture on the M25 to get here though) we have loads of National Trust hills around, geocaches (Englands Oldest), woodland, etc. There's decent hill walks around Coombe Hill and Chequers that we've done (though best to avoid walking around the PMs house...)

Comment: No one likes the M25... :)

Comment: Just watch out for the Scouts on their hikes...

Answer (score 1):

As you say it is rather flat around there. So you will be quite hard pressed to find any significant hills that close to you.

The most obvious area that comes to mind is the [Chilterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiltern_Hills). Although, that is still a good 2 hour drive so probably too far.

Various websites provide possible hikes for a given location. If you look through some of these you may find something of interest.

http://www.discoversuffolk.org.uk/walking-in-suffolk.aspx

http://www.gps-routes.co.uk/routes/home.nsf/walking-map/Suffolk

http://www.ramblers.org.uk/go-walking/find-a-walk-or-route.aspx (This one looks quite good but you have to sign up to actually view the routes).

I used to use another one for hikes around London/south coast a couple of years ago, which was good, but I can't remember what it was called/find it again.

If you go some where with cliffs coastal walks can also be relatively hilly. If there is anyone more local to you on here they may be able to give more specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

There are smaller hills around dedham vale area but with some great views.Polstead to Stoke Nayland is a great walk with a steep hill as well.

Comment: We certainly went to Dedham a few times - it’s very nice there.  We’ve “solved” our original issue somewhat now though - we moved to Cornwall :)